# How to add quotes for awk when single and double quotes are already used?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to write an alias so that my squeue command outputs only the simulations that are running. For my squeue command, I've an alias in my .bashrc as follow

```
alias sq='squeue -u as1056 --format="%.18i %.36j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.10L %.6D %.6C %.12P %R"'
```

With this, I can output the running simulations as

```
sq | awk '$4 == "R" {print $0}'
```

This works as intended in the command line. I now want to add this command as an alias

```
alias sqrun='sq | awk "$4 == \"R\" {print $0}"'
```

As you can see, the single quotes are already exhausted after the equal to sign and hence, double quotes are needed after the awk command. However, to match the pattern in column 4, I need to specify another string. Since single quote and double quotes have already been used, I'm not sure how I can specify a string in this scenario. I tried escaping the double quotes using backslash but it throws error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1:  == "R" {print -bash}
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ syntax error
```

So how should I specify an alias in such scenario?

Edit1: There's a dirty way of doing it by matching a simple R pattern across the sq command. The problem is that it often matches columns which contain the word "DRAINED". So I can use sed to delete such lines. So something like

```
sq | awk "/R/ {print $0}" | sed "/DRAINED/d"
```

won't run into the problem of having 3 quotes in the command. But I want to avoid this approach as it's not generic and may give erroneous results if there ever happens to be a column containing R and not containing the word "DRAINED".

PS: This is my first ever question on stackoverflow, so I'll appreciate your feedback if you notice any mistakes in the way I've asked this question!

Comment: Use a function instead of an alias and it would be easier

Comment: Thanks for this tip! In general usage, is it preferable to define functions in .bashrc over aliases? Or did you just mention it to avoid the problem with quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a simple:

```sh
alias sqrun='sq | awk '\''$4 == "R" {print $0}'\'
```

or with a function, like @DiegoTorresMilano suggested (but unlike aliases, it's not so easy to find a function name that you forgot):

```sh
sqrun() { sq | awk '$4 == "R" {print $0}'; }
```

or if there are several aliases to define:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# A little magic that will show you the way:
while IFS='' read -r cmd
do
    # define a dummy alias
    alias "unamed=$cmd"
    # then show it
    alias unamed
done <<'EOF'
squeue -u as1056 --format="%.18i %.36j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.10L %.6D %.6C %.12P %R"
sq | awk '$4 == "R" {print $0}'
EOF
```

<sup>now you can copy paste the output into your .bashrc and set a name for your aliased commands</sup>

**notes:**

- `<<'EOF'` ... `EOF` is a *quoted* [here-document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04); It will feed the stdin of a command (the `while` loop) with its content. When *quoted* it means that the shell won't expand anything inside of it.
- The `read` command reads a line from stdin (feeded with the here-document). The `IFS=''` and the `-r` option are there to prevent `read` from modifying the line.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not that well versed in bash, so I didn't know how to define functions so far. What you wrote worked exactly as intended! Would you be kind enough to explain the third block of code you wrote? It looks super useful as I have lot of alias commands, but a lot of things in there are new to me and I'm not sure what I should search in order to understand it.

Comment: I added some explanations, I hope that it'll be enough ;-)

Comment: Do not write a loop to process a here document to create aliases. Just, no.

Comment: Functions are not hard to find. Bash completes on their names, and you can always type `set` to view the list.  If you named all your function starting with a lower case letter, then `set | grep '^[a-z]'`. That cuts down on the stuff from the distro profile scripts that uses leading underscores or CAPS.

Comment: @Kaz I don't use functions for replacing aliases, but they can do the job, yes. What's so wrong with defining aliases through a heredoc and a loop? there's no escaping issues, no double/single quote problems, easy to read and maintain, but a little processing is required.

Answer (score 1):

The awk script contains  `$` and when you change the quotes around the awk script from `'` to `"`, it makes bash treat them as variables to substitute. You have to also escape `$`:

```sh
alias sqrun='sq | awk "\$4 == \"R\" {print \$0}"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I should have notice that bash also uses $ so there may be some conflict.

Answer (score 0):

you can chain single quoted sections by double quoting single quotes

```
alias sqrun='sq | awk '"'"' $4 == "R" {print $0} '"'"' '
```

added extra spaces for clarity but not needed.  However these nested quotes can become really hard to read and probable not a good idea except only for trivial cases and throw away scripts.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when just run `sq | awk '"'"' $4 == "R" {print $0} '"'"'` in the command line, it outputs the entire sq command, not just the running simulations.